# How do I implement sqlx::FromRow trait maually?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I am trying to manually implement `sqlx::FrowRow` instead of using `derive`, since some custom initialization logic is needed (ex. convert integer `i16` to enum).

Default impl is generated like this:

```rust
use sqlx::FromRow;

impl FromRow for User {
    fn from_row(row: &'r R) -> Result<Self, sqlx::Error> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

But it's unclear, what lifetime and type should I use.

Comment: try removing the lifetime annotation, most probably you do not need it.

Comment: Trait FromRow actually has specified lifetime `pub trait FromRow<'r, R: Row>: Sized`

Comment: @FellowRustacean that's for the case where the output just borrows row data (usually because one of the row items is decoded to a borrow e.g. `&str` or `&[u8]`)

Comment: @Netwave sqlx already implements FromRow for tuples, the entire point of implementing FromRow by hand would be to create a more specific structure, and thus return that.

Comment: @Netwave why would it be consumed by sqlx? It's `FromRow` not `ToRow`, it's the trait which converts records *out* of the database, and thus to application types. You could go through an intermediate tuple reification but... why?

Comment: @Masklinn, sorry, I understood it the other way around. In this case you could implement `From` for the tuple type returned by FromRow too.

Comment: @Netwave sure but all it'd do is add verbosity and intermediate failure case e.g. now you'd need to handle failures in the conversion between a row and a tuple, and then failures in the conversion between a tuple and your own type (e.g. values which are out of range for your type).

Comment: @Masklinn, absolutely!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `FromRow` trait is extremely generic since it is used for different backend databases that may support different types. You can see how many generic constraints are needed to implement a simple struct by looking at what `#[derive(FromRow)]` generates (via `cargo expand`):

```
use sqlx::FromRow;

#[derive(FromRow)]
struct User {
    name: String,
    status: i16,
}

// generates

impl<'a, R: ::sqlx::Row> ::sqlx::FromRow<'a, R> for User
where
    &'a ::std::primitive::str: ::sqlx::ColumnIndex<R>,
    String: ::sqlx::decode::Decode<'a, R::Database>,
    String: ::sqlx::types::Type<R::Database>,
    i16: ::sqlx::decode::Decode<'a, R::Database>,
    i16: ::sqlx::types::Type<R::Database>,
{
    fn from_row(row: &'a R) -> ::sqlx::Result<Self> {
        let name: String = row.try_get("name")?;
        let status: i16 = row.try_get("status")?;
        ::std::result::Result::Ok(User { name, status })
    }
}
```

It has to constrain that the columns can be indexed by name as well as constrain that `String` and `i16` are valid and can be decoded from the database.

Doing it yourself, you're probably better off picking which [database `Row` type](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.5.1/sqlx/trait.Row.html#implementors) you intend to use (`AnyRow`, `MssqlRow`, `MySqlRow`, `PgRow`, `SqliteRow`) and implement it for that. Here using `PgRow` for postgres:

```
use sqlx::{Row, FromRow, Error};
use sqlx::postgres::PgRow;

struct User {
    name: String,
    status: i16,
}

impl<'r> FromRow<'r, PgRow> for User {
    fn from_row(row: &'r PgRow) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let name = row.try_get("name")?;
        let status = row.try_get("status")?;

        Ok(User{ name, status })
    }
}
```

I do wonder though if there's a different recommendation for doing custom transformations (via a DTO or some other mechanism).